# What is dllspec(dllimport) and dllspec(dllexport) means

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport

After googling, i came to know that Dllimport makes the function available for other modules,

is it mandatory to declare function with extern "c" identifier?

Also, Dllexport means, Dll itself uses the function while compiling it says. so by default all

functions present in DLL are  dllexport?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`__declspec(dllexport)` exports a symbol. It makes it available from outside a DLL.

`__declspec(dllimport)` imports a symbol. It practically says "this symbol is not defined in this application, it needs to be imported from a DLL file".

You don't have to declare it with `extern "C"`. If you don't use `extern "C"`, then the symbol will be exported as a C++ symbol, and you will only be able to call it from C++ (and languages that support calling C++ DLLs). If you use `extern "C"`, then the symbol will be exported as a C symbol, and you will be able to call it from languages that support caling C DLLs.

If you want to use your DLL in C#, you will need to use `extern "C"`.

Here is an excellent tutorial that shows you how to use a C++ DLL in C#: [How to marshal a C++ class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class). I have used solution A in many projects at work.

Also, here is a short tutorial on how you can use a C++ DLL in another C++ application: [How to create and use DLL in C++](http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/blog:1).

Answer (score 11):

No -- dllexport means you're exporting it from the DLL (or from an executable) so that other modules (DLLs or executables) can use that function.

dllimport is used to declare a function that's implemented in a DLL (or, again, executable).

So, in a typical case, you'll have something like:

```
#ifdef BUILDDLL
#define DLL declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Then each public function the DLL will be marked as `DLL`:

```
DLL int dosomething(int);
```

Then, when you're building the DLL, you'll define `BUILDDLL`, to have all those functions marked as dllexport. Otherwise, you'll include the same header in client code that needs to use the function(s). It won't define `BUILDDLL`, so they'll all be marked as dllimport instead, so when it comes to link time, it'll create a link to that DLL instead of trying to satisfy those functions from someplace like the standard library.

Comment: dllimport is used to declare a function that's implemented in a DLL?, what is the use of this DLLimport?

Comment: @LLL: It lets the compiler know that it's coming from a DLL. A function coming from a DLL is always called via a pointer, so the compiler has to know enough to generate that.

Comment: @LLL Let's say you are making two projects: MyDLL and MyApp. You define a function in MyDLL, and you import the MyDLL.dll file into MyApp.exe and call the function from there. You need to use `__declspec(dllexport)` in the MyDLL project (to mark that you are exporting the function. And you need to use `__declspec(dllimport)` in the MyApp project, to import the function from the DLL.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, can you please clarify something.  The `#ifdef BUILDDLL` should be unique to each project (or solution) right?  So that when you add header files from an already built dll you get the correct ones with dllexport and the others should be dllimport.  Is this right?

Comment: @Ben: If you're going to build a DLL that exports some functions of its own, and imports some functions from other DLLs, then yes each would need to use a different name.

Comment: @Ove Does it mean that both in the MyDLL and the MyApp, one has to write _declspec(dllimport) in order to import the function from the DLL?... It only makes sense to me that you type _declspec(dllimport) in MyApp....

Comment: Best explaination. Clearly mentions with an example

Answer (score 0):

It also means that entries (in the form of static import and export tables) are created (by the linker) in the exe, dll..files, which document the dependencies between a provider and a consumer.