# How can I convert an existing project with .c and .h files into a dynamic link library in visual studio 2019?

Tags: c++, c, dll, header-files, ethercat

I am using the simple Open EtherCAT Master (SOEM) https://github.com/OpenEtherCATsociety/SOEM. I want to use the existing files in SOEM to create a .dll dynamic link library to build other projects with. I have tried creating a DLL in visual studio and simply uploading all the .c and .h files from SOEM to the DLL. When I do this, some of the header files are not recognized. Specifically the OSAL and OSHW header files. I'm not sure if this is a general issue between the header files or if this is an issue specific to the SOEM files. I would think that once you put all the .c and .h files in the same project, they would all be able to include each other.

Comment: I would have added a tag related to *ms visual studio*

Comment: Please expand your question. For example, how do you create the DLL?  What is the error message for "not recognized header files"? How do you compile your app using the DLL and the headers? What do you mean by "uploading" header files to the DLL?

Comment: If the library did not support building as a shared library this is not going to be a trivial task for msvc. You may want to check the CMake project generation if it has a BUILD_SHARED option.

Comment: ***I have tried creating a DLL in visual studio and simply uploading all the .c and .h files from SOEM to the DLL*** You will have to modify the headers to use dllexport when building and dllimport when using the dll if the library does not already support that. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222566/what-is-dllspecdllimport-and-dllspecdllexport-means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222566/what-is-dllspecdllimport-and-dllspecdllexport-means)

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel (especially if you have limited or no knowledge in the field)? https://github.com/OpenEtherCATsociety/SOEM#building

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the DLL:

1. put all .c and .h files into dll project
2. set directories to all files in solution properties > configuration properties > c/c++ > additional include directories
3. add additional dependecies to libraries for wpcap and others (Ws2_32.lib, wpcap.lib, winmm.lib)
   solution properties > configuration properties > linker > input > additional dependecies
4. set directories for wpcap libraries in solution properties > configuration properties > linker > general > additional library directories
5. build was successful after step 4